# stackoverflow favicon counter

Tags: script

### Screenshot

[image: favicon counter]

### About

I'm very like to answer questions on stackoverflow, but also I like to pin tabs in browser. It's hard to check how many unread questions I have on my favorite tag, so I decide to write script that will show unread questions counter in favicon.

#### License

MIT License

#### Download

- [Direct link at userscripts.org](http://userscripts.org/scripts/source/137743.user.js)
- [Project at userscripts.org](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/137743)
- [Project at GitHub](https://github.com/antyrat/stackoverflow-favicon-counter)

#### Platform

Should work in Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox (with installed Greasemonkey extension) and Opera and others browsers that supports user scripts.

More about installation info at [`scripts`](https://stackapps.com/tags/script/info) wiki tag.

### Contact

See my [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/186535/antyrat) at stackoverflow for contact details.

### Code

JavaScript

Comment: Can you make something like this, but then for the inbox / notification part of stackoverflow???